# How to get Touch MapPin lattitude?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

We need functionality to allow touch on MapPin. and on touch, draw route between current location and touchpin. touch pins are coming from xml file and binding to map control.

Following is my code.

I am getting error

```
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Latitude' property not found on 'MapPin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='Latitude' DataItem='MapPin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='txtLatitude'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

XAML:

```
<map:MapControl x:Name="map1" 
                    LandmarksVisible="True"
                        Loaded="map1_Loaded">
            <map:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapItems" >
                <map:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="stckPin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Tapped="stckPin_Tapped">
                            <Image x:Name="imgPin" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/icon.png"
                            map:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}" Opacity="0.8"
                            map:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{Binding NAP}"
                            Height="50" Width="50" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtLatitude" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Latitude, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource DoubleConverter1}}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </map:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </map:MapItemsControl>
        </map:MapControl>
```

C#:

```
namespace MapLocatorNamespace
{
    public sealed partial class MapLocator : Page
    {
        private void stckPin_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StackPanel stkPin = (StackPanel)sender;
            double loLatitude = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBlock)stkPin.Children[1]).Text);
        }
    }
    public class DoubleConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            var doubleNumber = (double)value;
            return doubleNumber.ToString("0.00#################");
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

how can i bind Latitude to textblock and get it at codebehind ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this myself,

What i have done is,
I have add int column index to may mapitem class, and added it in to 'Tag' attribute of image.
on Tap event i get this tag and from this index i can search in my list and and get tapped pin.

Now I am having Pin whole detail, and from Current location and This pin location i can draw route.

Thank you.